# Exchanging info between Python and PostgreSQL

Tags: python, database, postgresql, optimization

Here is the situation:

I have a process in Python that needs to take some info out of some tables on a PostgreSQL database. There's a lot of info and about 10, 15 tables. It's basically a cycling process that extracts the data of all the employees, one by iteration. The number of employees goes from 20 to 130 and it could be higher.

I was wandering which of these options would be the best in terms of timing:

1) to query the data I need every time I need it, which would mean a lot of smaller queries to those big tables. Assuming of course I won't query the same data a lot of times, but I would access the same table repeatedly.

2) to load only the bigger tables (in which case I would need to know what you consider big) before the for cycle, and to save them in memory, grouping them by employee, then accessing to the stored data in each iteration.

3) to load every table at first, and make no more queries during the cycle.

Also, I would like to know which one would be best if chosen 2 or 3: to save the data in a global variable or to pass it a lot of times as parameter.

If you need me to rephrase just ask. I think I need some experienced opinion on the matter, because I need the process to be as efficient as possible.

Thanks in advance (or at least for reading up to here) :)

EDIT: Each employee may take more than a couple of seconds, making the process a little slower than I'd like for, say, 100 employees. I need it to be as fast as possible.

Comment: Data of 20 to 130 employees *seems like* practically nothing. Have you been experiencing slow performance? If you make an API module for your database access use-case to abstract away the actual method used to retrieve the information, you can solve this later **if** it becomes a problem.

Comment: "The number of employees goes from 20 to 130 and it could be higher.", how much higher? Millions? If not, what's wrong with a simple query to get the data you need? That's proven technology and works in (almost) any environment. This is what we do on a database with 4 million pretty active customers.

Comment: OK, I'll edit my question. The thing is, you're right, the number of employees itself is not high. The problem is that each employee has large amounts of data. Then, if one employee takes roughly 3 secs, 120 would take 6 minutes approx, and I'd like to do it faster if possible.

Comment: "Then, if one employee takes roughly 3 secs": that is amazingly slow... is your DB using massive BLOBs or something?

Comment: @Kevin indeed it is. That's because of the amount of data, and (maybe, that would be my question) the number of querys I'm making to the DB. The time improved when I started storing some tables at the beginning of the process in memory. I wanted to know if I was in the right track...

Comment: Most standard SQL libraries (e.g. [psycopg2](http://initd.org/psycopg/)) do some caching and prefetching automatically when you run queries through their cursor objects.  I'm not sure you can realistically out-optimize those implementations, since if you consume too much memory, you'll start swapping, which is definitely a Bad Thing.  Can you show us the code you have so far?

Comment: It sounds like you want option (4), which you didn't mention: Use joins to extract the sets of data you want by asking the database for the dataset, rather than doing series of small queries. I think you're trying to solve the wrong problem.